# Windows 10 Google API possible excessive path length issue?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

The code snippets below are part of the code I use on Win10 64-bit in a C# .net6 application that uses Google APIs to upload files to Google Drive.  The code works fine but I ran into a problem when trying to change the location of the refresh token file.

In the code snippet below there are four different versions of how I obtain a path to a directory that contains a refresh token file.  Each of the directories contains the same valid refresh token file.

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    // The directory specified below stores the user's access and refresh token
    // file, and is created automatically when the authorization flow completes
    // for the first time.
    string credPath = Path.Combine("./x");
    OR
    string credPath = Path.Combine("./x", "y");
    OR
    string credPath = Path.Combine("./GoogleApiTokens");
    OR
    string credPath = Path.Combine("./GoogleApiTokens", "UploadToGoogleDrive");
        
    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
        Scopes,
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
}
```

However, in the later code below,

```
FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request = googleDriveService.Files.Create(body, stream, body.MimeType);
request.Upload();
string fileID = request.ResponseBody.Id;
```

request.ResponseBody is always null if I used the following to get the path, while it works perfectly if I used the first three versions:

```
string credPath = Path.Combine("./GoogleApiTokens", "UploadToGoogleDrive");
```

All I can think of is that somehow the 256-character path limit is being violated.  However, the path even after the ./ is replaced by the full path and the name of the file in that directory is included is only about 170 characters.  Maybe internally maybe even more characters are being added for some reason?  I thought about enabling "long paths" but first I would like to know what is actually going on.

Comment: Can you check the status of that request? Ie something like `var result = request.Upload()` and then check `result.Status` ?

Comment: I would isolate the usage of `FileDataStore` from everything else. You don't need to make a request to test whether the `FileDataStore` you're creating is functional. Just create the store and call `await store.StoreAsync("key", "value");` - does the file get created? If you then call `await store.GetAsync<string>("key")` does that evaluate to "value"?